# How to force MyCelium wallet to show all transactions

Tags: lost-transactions

Have been using MyCelium wallet regularly for the past 3yrs without any issues.  Last week after I transferred some funds, UI seemed buggy/laggy, not refreshing properly.  I uninstalled the app and did a fresh install. Restored from my master seed and to my horror:  the balance is WAY off.  I look at the sync'd transactions and it has stopped after 7/18/2018 !  I force as reload, refresh, everything I can think of and it's as though all further transactions have disappeared?!  I've tried loading in electrum wallet, same result.  Anyone know wtf is happening?  why can't I see the up-2-date transactions and why is my balance off by more than 10 btc ?!  Any help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: Use better bitcoin wallets: https://bitcoinwallet.guide/

Comment: Did you ever import private-keys into MyCelium?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick no sir I did not.  I had thought of that -- how the master seed and backups only applied to anything derived from that seed and not to accounts imported via private-keys.  But no, only used the one account on MyCelium .. I have a ledger for cold storage and used MyCelium for "everyday fund transactions".  Everything was really fine until last week .. the weird bug/hang seems to have 'cut the chain" so to speak and disassociated many yrs worth of transactions starting from 2018-> present.  I've never encountered anything like this before :\